# PHP PDO sorting list of results alphabetically not being sorted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-order-by

I have the following code:

```
    $sqlQueryVendorId = $dbh->prepare("SELECT business_name, profile_id 
        FROM $tableVendorProfiles 
        WHERE ((vendor_id_1 = :vendor_id_1 OR vendor_id_2 = :vendor_id_2) 
            AND profile_id = :profile_id) 
        ORDER BY business_name ASC");
    $sqlQueryVendorId->execute(array(
        ':vendor_id_1' => $vendorId, 
        ':vendor_id_2' => $vendorId, 
        'profile_id' => $profileId));
    $sqlResultVendorId = $sqlQueryVendorId->fetch();

while ($sqlResultVendorId = $sqlQueryVendorId->fetch()){
    //Get values from table
    $businessNameDB = $sqlResultVendorId['business_name'];
    echo $businessNameDB;
}
```

For some reason even though I tried many times the list is not sorted alphabetical. I'm not sure what is wrong. It is like `ORDER BY business_name ASC` is being ignored

My list is as follows:

```
Mary's Lamb
Bouncy Castles
Ping Pong Ball
```

I want it to be sorted as follows:

```
Bouncy Castles
Mary's Lamb
Ping Pong Ball
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and how it is being sorted.

Comment: Why do you fetch data 1 time before the loop? `$sqlResultVendorId = $sqlQueryVendorId->fetch();`

Comment: What Charset does the table use? (the charset affects sorting, but should not affect it this much :/ ), Also try without ASC, it shouold sort it by ascending by default...

Comment: @Richard87 I am using UTF8

Comment: Yeah, I thought so :P Then its not that... Can you try without the outer parenthesis in the where clause? And those the query work when you execute it directly on the mysql server?

Comment: Could some of the rows have spaces at the beginning of the business name? Space sorts before letters, so those will be put first. But the spaces won't be visible on an HTML page.

Comment: could you show the contents of `show create table my_table_name`